# Scroll view is not working in android in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

i am using scroll view in react-native to move the view, i wrote like this  `scrollView.scrollTo({ y: newY, animated: true });`

```
scrolldown(){
    this.refs.ScrollView.scrollTo({y:windowSize.width*2/9,animated: true});
  }
  scroll(){
    this.refs.ScrollView.scrollTo({y:windowSize.width*2/23,animated: true});
  }
<ScrollView ref='ScrollView'>
                 <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
             <Image style={styles.inputPassword} source={require('image!locker')}/>
             <TextInput
               ref='SecondInput'
               password={true}
               style={styles.email}
               value={this.state.password} 
               placeholder="Password"
               onFocus={this.scrolldown.bind(this)}
               returnKeyType='next'
                 onChange={this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)}
              />
          </View>
.
.
.
.

</ScrollView>
```

It works in IOS fine,But not working in android, any one please give me suggestions that how to resolve it, Any help much appreciated

Comment: Can you share an example of the code you're using?

Comment: @QMFNP above i update it with my update can you check it give me suggestions